# Android Studio getting hanged frequently

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a strange problem with Android Studio IDE. i am using Android studio 2.1.2. The problem is that an activity in my Android studio, is getting hanged frequently and also i cant able to do any changes in it including typing. I tried Invalidating and Restart studio IDE also. Any one faced this issue with Studio IDE before this?

Comment: Mention your computer specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar issue with Android studio. The problem is you are using a outdated version. You should readily change to newer version. Studio SDK uses a lot of RAM and so when it is overloaded, it will get studio hanged.

In your case, upgrade your RAM also. Minimum 8 GB ram is advisable to have for IDE.

And a worst case remember, that when you run your program, surely you will  not have the apk with recent changes. It will run the older apk in memory stack. At those times, it is advisable to shut down your system and restart it.

We have raised queries reg it to Google and the answer from them is also to update the version. This has been fixed in new Updated version of Android Studio. Cheers !

Comment: For me, this thing worked.    File->Other Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tool-> Gradle->Check on Offline work. And everything started working fine. Grade was getting some upgrade all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your Android Studio based on your machine configuration:

Please go through the below link and configure Android Studio accordingly:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you project is large then this kind of problem happened.
I had same problem , I solve this following way:

1.) Increase HeapSize of android studio from property file:

-Xms256m

-Xmx750m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

To

-Xms256m

-Xmx1280m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

OR

-Xms1024m

-Xmx4096m

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m

based on you RAM Size, and Restart Android studio.

2.) Once syncing is done try to use offline sync

File->Setting->Gradle->EnableOffline work check box.

Hope this help you !